# R - Shiny Conditional Input

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get input choices dependent on previous input.

```
require(shiny)
require(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(id1 = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),
         id2 = c(rep("C",3),rep("D",3),rep("E",4)),
         id3 = c(rep("F",2),rep("G",3),rep("H",5)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('id1', 'ID1', choices = unique(dat$id1)),
    selectInput("id2", "ID2", choices = unique(dat$id2)),
    selectInput("id3", "ID3", choices = unique(dat$id3))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

observeEvent(
            { 
            input$id1 
            },{
            input$id2
            temp <- dat %>% filter(id1%in%input$id1)
            updateSelectInput(session,"id2",choices = unique(temp$id2))
            }
        )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This works for Input 1 and 2, however if i add another Input to `observeEvent`, the app chrashes. E.g:

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {

observeEvent(
                { 
                input$id1 
                },{
                input$id2
                temp <- dat %>% filter(id1%in%input$id1)
                updateSelectInput(session,"id2",choices = unique(temp$id2))
                },{
                input$id3
                temp <- dat %>% filter(id1%in%input$id1 & id2%in%input$id2)
                updateSelectInput(session,"id3",choices = unique(temp$id3))
                }
    )
}
```

How can I pass further Inputs to `observeEvent` ?

Comment: can you share what error comes in console?

Comment: @TedoG. `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)` Which is strange, since the Input is inside the reactive Expression.

Comment: Have you tried moving your `dat` data variable into a reactive expression?

Answer (score 3):

Update: I found a solution for the problem. I wrapped the Inputs in a `reactive` function, split the Output and passed it to the corresponding `observeEvent` functions.

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {


change <- reactive({
    unlist(strsplit(paste(c(input$id1,input$id2,input$id3),collapse="|"),"|",fixed=TRUE))

    })

observeEvent(input$id1,{  
                    temp <- dat %>% filter(id1 %in% change()[1])
                    updateSelectInput(session,"id2",choices = unique(temp$id2))
                    }
                )

observeEvent(input$id2,{  
                    temp <- dat %>% filter(id1 %in% change()[1] & id2 %in% change()[2])
                    updateSelectInput(session,"id3",choices = unique(temp$id3))
                    }
                )           
    }
```